# How to call a function within a function from a module

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, import, module

I'm having an issue when I attempt to unit test my code. I have a script named "compute_stats2.py" which contains a defined function "compute_stats" within a function "main" because I want to build in a command line argument within main later down the line. The functions used in compute_stats are all defined within main, but I excluded them for the sake of neatness, please let me know if you need to take a look at it. That being said I have been attempting to unit test (see code below) and every time I attempt to run the test this error occurs.

> AttributeError: module 'compute_stats2' has no attribute 'compute_stats'

I'm wondering if I'm not calling the function correctly within the unit test code. Any suggestions on how to make that call better.

P.S. apologizes in advance if it's a really obvious fix, I'm not the strongest coder.

---

## compute_stats2.py

```
def main():

  def compute_stats(values):
    if not values:
      return None
    else:
      o_min=minimum_of_list(values)
      o_max=values[-1]
      o_avg=average_of_list(values)
      o_median=median_of_list(values)
      return(o_min, o_max, o_avg, o_median)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

## test_compute_stats2.py

```
import unittest
import compute_stats2

class TestComputeStats2(unittest.TestCase):

def test_none_from_none(list):
    ret = compute_stats2.compute_stats(None)
    list.assertIsNone(ret)

def test_empty_list(list):
    ret = compute_stats2.compute_stats([])
    list.assertIsNone(ret)

def test_even_elements_list(list):
    ret = compute_stats2.compute_stats([1,2,3,4])
    list.assertEqual(ret, (1, 4, 2.5, 2.5))

def test_odd_elements_list(list):
    ret = compute_stats2.compute_stats([1,2,12])
    list.assertEqual(ret, (1, 12, 5, 2))

def test_single_element_list(list):
    ret = compute_stats2.compute_stats([43])
    list.assertEqual(ret, (43, 43, 43, 43))
```

Answer (score 1):

`compute_stats()` is an inner function inside `main()`. Since you don't use it internally you can take it out

```
def main(): # can be removed if there is no other use
  pass


def compute_stats(values):
  if not values:
    return None
  else:
    o_min=minimum_of_list(values)
    o_max=values[-1]
    o_avg=average_of_list(values)
    o_median=median_of_list(values)
    return(o_min, o_max, o_avg, o_median)
```

By the way, if the tests are inside class they need `self` as first parameter. You should also change `list` as parameter name, it's a built in name.

```
def test_none_from_none(self, test_list):
```

Answer (score 1):

You've built a local function inside of `main` that is called `compute_stats`. The execution of `compute_stats` will only ever occur when `main` is called due to scoping rules. As a result you would need to import and run main if you were wanting to run `compute_stats` in it's current state.

It would be a good idea to move the `compute_stats` outside of `main` if you'd like to import it. You would no longer be building a local function that has scope limited under main.

e.g.

```py
def compute_stats(val):
 pass

def main():
 pass
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `compute_stats` is not a closure because it doesn't reference any names from the scope of `main`. It is simply a local function. In fact if it were a closure, then your suggested decoupling would not be possible (at least not without making other changes to the program)

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Thanks for the correction! I've edited my wording to remove the word closure :)